# how to work with multiple action and get count using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

here i have create one query for the show count date wise in the chart. and i have used mongodb. and i have one object and in the object store multiple data and separate with one value **Action**. i want to show count date wise Action like Comment,like both action count want show. right now i am just show comment count. i want also get like count.
here below i have listed my object and query.

here this is my array of the object =>

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
   "Action" : "Comment",
   "datetime" : 1507099928000 // 4th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
  "Action" : "Comment",
   "datetime" : 1507099928000  // 4th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c30"),
    "Action" : "Comment",
   "datetime" : 1507186328000 // 5th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 }
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
  "Action" : "Comment",
  "datetime" : 1507193528000 // 5th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 },
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
   "Action" : "Comment",
  "datetime" : 1507279928000 // 6th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 }
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c30"),
   "Action" : "Comment",
   "datetime" : 1507020728000 // 3th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 }
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
  "Action" : "Comment",
  "datetime" : 1507279928000  // 6th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 },
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
   "Action" : "like",
   "datetime" : 1507279928000  // 6th oct 2017 convert date just for info here write
 }
```

my current o/p =>

```
[ { _id: '03-10-2017', count: 1 },
  { _id: '04-10-2017', count: 2 },
  { _id: '05-10-2017', count: 2 },
  { _id: '06-10-2017', count: 2 } ]
```

my excepted o/p =>

```
[ { _id: '03-10-2017', count: 1 ,likecount:0},
  { _id: '04-10-2017', count: 2 ,likecount:0},
  { _id: '05-10-2017', count: 2,likecount:0 },
  { _id: '06-10-2017', count: 2,liekcount:1},
```

this is my query =>

```
InstaAc.aggregate([
                        {
                            "$match": {
                                "_id": ObjectId("595e3b2033961713940442cf"),
                                "History.datetime": {
                               "$lte": 1507529239000, "$gte": 1507012285558
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$unwind": "$History"
                        },
                        {
                            "$match": {
                                "History.datetime": {
                                  "$lte": 1507529239000, "$gte": 1507012285558
                                },
                                "History.Action": {
                                    $eq: "comment"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$addFields": {
                                "History.datetime": {
                                    "$add": [new Date(0), "$History.datetime"]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                            {
                                "$group": {
                                    "_id": {
                                        "$dateToString": {
                                            "format": "%d-%m-%Y",
                                            "date": "$History.datetime"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "count": {
                                        "$sum": 1
                                    }                                    
                                }
                            },                           
                            {
                                "$sort": {
                                    "_id": 1
                                }
                            }
               ]).exec(function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err); 
}
else {
    console.log(data);        
}
 })
```

any one how can do that then please let me know.

Comment: Something like  `{     "$match": {       "_id": ObjectId("595e3b2033961713940442cf"),  "History.datetime": {                                "$lte": 1507529239000, "$gte": 1507012285558                                 }, History.Action: {$in:["Comment", "like"]}}}` for both match stages

Comment: yes i am try but return same o/p

Comment: how can add onther new count in the o/p for like?

Comment: and i have tow $match  statement show in which statement in to add $unwind above or below ?

Comment: Please read the comment carefully. You should include it both matches stage.

Comment: yes i do but this like count add in to comment count. not show onther ,likecount = 1

Comment: i want like this { _id: '06-10-2017', count: 2,liekcount:1}

Comment: To get expected output you have to update $group to include likecount field. `likecount:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$History.Action","like"]}, 1, 0]}}`

Comment: yes thank you so much finally i get it result again thank you so muc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update first `$match` to

```
{
  "$match": {
    "_id": ObjectId("595e3b2033961713940442cf"),
    "History.datetime": {
      "$lte": 1507529239000,
      "$gte": 1507012285558
    },
    "History.Action": {
      "$in": [
        "Comment",
        "like"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and second `$match` to

```
{
  "$match": {
    "History.datetime": {
      "$lte": 1507529239000,
      "$gte": 1507012285558
    },
    "History.Action": {
      "$in": [
        "Comment",
        "like"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and `$group` to

```
{
  "likecount": {
    "$sum": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$eq": [
            "$History.Action",
            "like"
          ]
        },
        1,
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello i am working with now object and i am make new query for the object then after i am getting error "date is not defind" so how can fix it?

Comment: using this same for o/p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766368/getting-error-like-date-is-not-defind-using-nodejs-with-mogodb please visit this

Comment: how can i print my date again i am getting error. actully i have changed my schema so right now i am getting count form the object so now i am getting error for the date and don't print date.

Comment: Hi please help on this post and give me some hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072791/how-to-remove-time-form-unixtime-stamp-date-using-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment81093717_47072791

Comment: i am getting some issue on generate dates with remove time form the date.