# How to generate excel file using node.js?

Tags: node.js, excel

Hi I am go for the generate excel file form the array but I am not getting successes. I am work using node.js and I am use npm package for generate excel file but I am not getting any data in excel file. excel is generate but not getting any type of data in my file. so any one know where is my mistake then please let me know how can fix it.

**This is my array and query =>**

```
            var XLSX = require('xlsx');
                   var Array = [];
                    Array.push({
                        username: 'Carakc',
                        fullName: 'Crack',
                        followingCount: 2655,
                        followerCount: 466,
                        biography: 'I am new man'                                                      
                    },
                  {
                      username: 'mahi',
                      fullName: 'Fit',
                      followingCount: 3011,
                      followerCount: 385,
                      biography: 'hello everyone!'                          
                  })

app.get(prefix + '/GetFollowersInExcel', function (req, res, next) {                                                                       
                    var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(Array);
                    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Followres");
                    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
                    res.end(wbout, 'binary');
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

**This is my service code =>**

```
GetFollowersInExcel: function (InstaId) {            
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: ONURL + "GetFollowersInExcel",
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }                
        }).then(function (data, status, xhr) {
            debugger;
            if (data.data.byteLength > 0) {
                var file = new Blob([data.data], { type: 'application/binary' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $('#getexcel').show();
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = fileURL;
                link.download = "myfile.xlsx";
                link.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(file);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        })
    },
```

**using this wave I am getting like this data in excel =>**

[image]

**I want like this data in excel file =>**

[image]

Comment: uhm... just an idea, I can't test it at the moment, but have you tried rename you `var Array` to something else? for instance `var blabla`... writing this: `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(Array);` sounds like if you are transforming the Array object to a sheet

Comment: @RobertoBisello you mean i need to change name of the variable of array? but i have try also like this still same issue

Comment: Those headers appear to be default properties you would see on an array (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833736/object-keys-returns-unexpected-keys-on-mongodb-object-from-collection for examples). It's not a duplicate as far as I can see, but the answers to that question may give a few pointers.

Comment: @AdrianWragg are you not aware with this issue please help me how can fix it

Comment: @Edit: if you already tried that, I've no idea, sorry, I'll try as soon as possible :)

Comment: guys any other wave to generate excel then also tell me so i can try with that

Comment: @Edit It's not an issue I have come across myself; that question may have similar solutions though. It looks like https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/659 may be helpful too.

Comment: guys i have try many waves and also change variable name and also put in the scope perfect but still i am getting issue and how can solved it idk i am more suffering to this issue

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your first code and I've found no errors, the resulting xlsx is perfect.

Peheraps I've found the problem: var Array is declared outside the app.get callback... Are you sure that your var Array can be correctly reached by XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet? it's in the same scope? or it's declared somewhere inaccessible?

try to declare it inside the callback and probably all will work well, and, if this is the case, you can use a class or a method to retrieve the var from outside ("how" depends on your code)

P.s. change the name of the var, is not a good habit overwrite the Array object ;)